# Using SDL_PollEvent vs SDL_PumpEvents

Tags: c++, c, events, sdl

I've been using SDL for a while now, but now it seems I've been doing things the wrong way when working with keyboard events.

Normally my main loop looks something like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    /* Some video system initializations */

    /* Main loop */
    for(;;) {
        SDL_PumpEvents();
        const unsigned char *key = SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr);

        /* Do something with the keys pressed */
    }
}
```

... and this has worked fine for me. But I've recently looked at some code examples, and technically all of them use a different pattern:

```cpp
int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    /* Some video system initializations */

    /* Main loop */
    for(;;) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            /* switch/case to know keys pressed */
        }
    }
}
```

So looking at SDL documentation I found that `SDL_PollEvent` does call `SDL_PumpEvents`. [SDL_PollEvent reference](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEvents%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29)

And what `SDL_PumpEvents` does is to gather the state of all input devices to generate event objets. [SDL_PumpEvents reference](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEvents%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29)

So in the first example, I'm not *flushing* the event queue, so why does it works without crashing? Is the second pattern the *correct* way of getting input state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `PumpEvents` modifies the global keyboard and mouse state, its precision may be not enough. Consider what happens when you have the mouse pressed, moved and released all in single frame - with `PumpEvents` you'll get the last position and 'released' state, but not the position of the first click or even the click event itself. It's the same for the keyboard - you get the 'latest' state but not the previous states of the keys in the order they were pressed/released. There are also a lot of 'special' events like window events, joysticks (SDL has an optional high-frequency background thread to poll the joystick and place events in the queue) and even hotplug events for audio devices and joysticks - you can't get that without inspecting the event queue.

Your program doesn't crash on overflow because SDL has an upper limit on how many events it can store in the queue - [currently 65535](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/3c6a6dad3487/src/events/SDL_events.c#l37).

Comment: That's interesting. So there should be no real difference in performance since events are created and saved into the queue anyway.

Comment: _SDL has an optional high-frequency background thread to poll the joystick and place events in the queue_. That sounds interesting. Is this documented somewhere? On first glance I couldn't find any reference.

Comment: @bluenote10 https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/d47c286b12eccee479ba57c8897092c6277ef962/include/SDL_hints.h#L1008 it seems it is only implemented on windows, i thought it is more widespread. But with wide adoption of USB HID joysticks i suppose that should no longer be a problem